# Replace tags with space in PHP for SEO Meta Description

Tags: php, mysql, tags, seo, meta-tags

I am trying to strip tags from HTML in a mySQL database to plain text for an SEO Meta Description. The HTML in the database looks like this:

```
<p>The Break-ezee is a vital piece of equipment for anyone when breaking horses - As used by Mary King.</p>
<p></p>
<p>The Break-ezee is an all in one progressive training product for use when breaking horses.</p>
```

I am using the following PHP to format it:

```
$showseodesc = trim(strip_tags(substr($showseoproduct['text'],0,160)));
```

This shows the following in the source of the site:

```
<meta name="description" content="The Break-ezee is a vital piece of equipment for anyone when breaking horses - As used by Mary King.

The Break-ezee is an all in one progressi" />
```

Is there anyway I can replace any tags (in this case <p>) so there are no spaces?

I am ideally looking for the Meta Description to look like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="The Break-ezee is a vital piece of equipment for anyone when breaking horses - As used by Mary King. The Break-ezee is an all in one progressi" />
```

Also, am I correct in thinking Google doesn't pick up extra spaces for the Meta Description?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str_replace`

`$showseodesc = str_replace(array('<p>', '</p>'), '', $showseodesc);`

`$showseodec = substr($showseoproduct['text'],0, 160);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using regular expressions.

```
$string = "<p>The Break-ezee is a vital piece of equipment for anyone when breaking horses - As used by Mary King.</p>";

print preg_replace("|<[^>]+>|si","",$string); // <-- strip all tags from a string.

print preg_replace("|<p[^>]*>|si","",$string); // <-- strip all <p...> tags from a string.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$showseodesc = trim(
                   preg_replace("/\n+/"," " , 
                               strip_tags(
                                         substr($showseoproduct['text'], 0, 160)
                                         )
                               )
                   );
```

Note `preg_replace`, that changes every newline to one space.

Answer (score 0):

str_replace is enough for this:-

```
$html = "<p>The Break-ezee is a vital piece of equipment for anyone when breaking horses - As used by Mary King.</p>
<p></p>
<p>The Break-ezee is an all in one progressive training product for use when breaking horses.</p>";

echo str_replace(array('<p>', '</p>'), '', $html);
```

Output:-

> The Break-ezee is a vital piece of equipment for anyone when breaking horses - As used by Mary King. The Break-ezee is an all in one progressive training product for use when breaking horses.